# Find a homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb C \to \Bbb R^*$ such that $\phi(i) = 2$.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Find a homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb C \to \Bbb R^*$ such that $\phi(i) = 2$.

I can't think of anything here, I can only get $\phi(a+bi) = 2^b,$ but I'm pretty sure I can't just extract the imaginary part like that.

If it was $\mathbb C^*$ instead of $\mathbb C$ then I know I can use absolute value / magnitude somehow but in this case it wouldn't be a homomorphism.

Comment: Why can’t you extract the imaginary part?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just assumed that the entire complex number z had to be explicitly used in the function, because that itself is the input. But this works so I guess there's no problem just extracting the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

Let $x=a+ib,y=c+id\in\Bbb C$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\phi(x+y)&=\phi((a+c)+i(b+d))\\
&=2^{b+d}\\
&=2^b2^d\\
&=\phi(a+ib)\phi(c+id)\\
&=\phi(x)\phi(y).
\end{align}$$

Thus $\phi:\Bbb C\to \Bbb R^*$ is indeed a homomorphism.

Moreover, $\phi(i)=\phi(0+i1)=2^1=2$.